# How do I format a UITextfield's text that happens to be a telephone number, in american style?

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, swift, uitextfield

Let's say I have this number **1234567890**

and I want it in this format **(xxx) xxx-xxxx**

So on the display I'd like it to display as **(123) 456-7890**

How would I achieve this?

Would I need to use some sort of regex on the textfield?

Thanks for your time

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
    NSCharacterSet *digits = [[NSCharacterSet decimalDigitCharacterSet] invertedSet];
    NSString *filtered = [[[textField text] componentsSeparatedByCharactersInSet: digits] componentsJoinedByString: @""];

    if ([filtered length] == 11) {
        NSString *formatted = [NSString stringWithFormat: @"(%@) %@-%@", [filtered substringWithRange: NSMakeRange(1, 3)], [filtered substringWithRange: NSMakeRange(4, 3)], [filtered substringWithRange: NSMakeRange(7, 4)]];
        [textField setText: formatted];
    } else if ([filtered length] == 10) {
        NSString *formatted = [NSString stringWithFormat: @"(%@) %@-%@", [filtered substringWithRange: NSMakeRange(0, 3)], [filtered substringWithRange: NSMakeRange(3, 3)], [filtered substringWithRange: NSMakeRange(6, 4)]];
        [textField setText: formatted];
    }
```

Comment: Worked well and led me to my answer in swift

Answer (score 4):

In case you are using Swift:

```
let phoneNum = activity["phoneNumber"] as String
let digits = NSCharacterSet.decimalDigitCharacterSet().invertedSet as NSCharacterSet
let filtered1 = phoneNum.componentsSeparatedByCharactersInSet(digits) as NSArray

let filtered = filtered1.componentsJoinedByString("") as NSString

if filtered.length == 11 {
    let formatted = NSString(format: "(%@) %@-%@", filtered.substringWithRange(NSMakeRange(1, 3)), filtered.substringWithRange(NSMakeRange(4, 3)), filtered.substringWithRange(NSMakeRange(7, 4))) as NSString

    phoneNumberField.text = formatted
} else if filtered.length == 10 {
    let formatted = NSString(format: "(%@) %@-%@", filtered.substringWithRange(NSMakeRange(0, 3)), filtered.substringWithRange(NSMakeRange(3, 3)), filtered.substringWithRange(NSMakeRange(6, 4))) as NSString

    phoneNumberField.text = formatted
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using [RMPhoneFormat](https://github.com/rmaddy/RMPhoneFormat).

From GitHub page: "RMPhoneFormat provides a simple to use class for formatting and validating phone numbers in iOS apps. The formatting should replicate what you would see in the Contacts app for the same phone number."